# Trying to get the id of a input type out of a JS variable

Tags: javascript, html

```
var askQuitHTMLMessage = 
"<p><strong>Waar moet rekening mee worden gehouden bij het inplannen?</strong></p>" +
"<p><strong>Vul de volgende gegevens in om het resultaat te bepalen:</strong></p>" +
"<p><input class='inplan_var' data='ingeplande_uren' type='checkbox' name='medewerkers' id='aantmdw'><strong>&#09; Aantal uren resource</strong></input></p>" +
"<p><input class='inplan_var' data='ervaring' type='checkbox' name='medewerkers' id='ervaring'><strong>&#09; Ervaring</strong></input></form></p>" +
"<p><input class='inplan_var' data='expertise' type='checkbox' name='medewerkers' id='expertise'><strong>&#09; Expertise</strong></input></form></p>" +
"<p><input class='inplan_var' data='etc' type='checkbox' name='medewerkers' id='etc'><strong>&#09; Etcetera</strong></input></form></p>";
```

How can i get the id of one of these input types inside the javascript variable?

Comment: What do you mean by 'one of these'? All of them, or any of them, or?

Comment: Any of them. How can i call one of the input elements.

Comment: get an element from these by id or get the id of an element in these?

Comment: Those arn't yet input elements with an id - they're just part of a string. Until you add them to a DOM (or, at least parse them with something like jQuery) they have no meaningful "id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that gets you an array of the ids

play with the code: https://jsbin.com/vejumo/edit?js,console

```
var askQuitHTMLMessage =  "...." // The string in the question

var tmpDiv = document.createElement('div');
tmpDiv.innerHTML = askQuitHTMLMessage;
var inputs = tmpDiv.querySelectorAll('input');
var ids = [];
inputs.forEach(function(input) {ids.push(input.id)})
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: And what if i want to make a certain input checked=true? How do i get it back in the html string

Comment: @MarkieDoe `tmpDiv.querySelectorAll('input#etc').checked = true;` this will turn the checkbox with the etc id to true. then just get the innerHTML of the tmpDiv `askQuitHTMLMessage  = tmpDiv.innerHTML`.

Comment: I tried tmpDiv.querySelectorAll('input#etc').checked = true; But this did not work for me, it's not checking it. When i console.log(tmpDiv.innerHTML) it also says it isn't checked.

Comment: You are correct, it modifies the DOM but does not set the attribute on the string. do this instead: `tmpDiv.querySelector('input#etc').setAttribute("checked","checked")`

Comment: This got it working for me! many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this should works for you

> $('input', $(askQuitHTMLMessage)).each(function(){ console.log( "id :" + $(this).attr('id') )})